# assigning a list of arrays in different length to a Pandas Series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, series

I'm stuck with storing arrays of regression coefficients (in different length) into a series.  I use a for loop to call the regressions over time.  Across the training period, the regression only returns an array of size 1 with the intercept.  Beyond the training period, the coefficients will be of intercept plus the different factors (the factors applicable through each time point may vary).  That's where my Python code crashes with the error of: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

```
tempS = pd.Series(index = range(len(temp)))
...... # for loop over i
    model = linear_model.OLS(y, x)
    results = model.fit()
    tempS[i] = results.params.values
```

Can someone shed me some lights on how to store arrays of different length into my series variable tempS?

Comment: What does `tempS.dtype` give? I suspect `x` is a series of `float64`, in which case you can't assign arrays to elements of the series, only floats. If you explicitly set the dtype to `object`, you can, but I don't see the point of setting series elements to arrays. Maybe you intended for `tempS` to be a plain old `list`?

Comment: why are you putting arrays in a `pd.Series`??

Comment: the above comments are referring to the fact that pandas.Series is not designed to hold lists, and if your intention is simply to loop over the elements, the performance of a Series will be worse than that of a simple list or dictionary. Pandas is designed to perform best doing vectorized operations over continuous blocks of data, not just to be a container for native python objects.

Comment: Thanks, Pranav and Michael, for your kind replies, greatly appreciated.  As you can tell, I'm at beginner's level with Python.  Indeed, tempS.dtype gives me float64.  The only reason I'm using series is that I know the array of coefficients I get from the regressions will be of different length over time, depending on which factors pass the screening test out of each cross section.  Are you telling me I should use a list or dictionary in this case?